# Scraping an AJAX generated JSON feed

Tags: ajax, json, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape a webpage which is generating pages via an AJAX call from a JSON response. This is the code on the page:

```
  var data = JSON.stringify({
    organizationId: organizationId,
    concertId: concertId,
     })

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/getdata",
    data: data,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  });
}
```

So,  I try to scrape this via a Request

> data = '{"organizationId":"1","concertId":"8918"}'
>
> url = 'http://www.domain.com/ajax/getdata'
>
> request = Request( url = url ,
>
> method='POST',
>
> body=data,
>
> headers={'Content-Type':'application/json'})

But this doesn't work; the parse function is not called. Am i missing something?

Comment: there is not any issue in scrapy, but in your code , so definitely you should provide more information for getting appropriate answer like exact URL , Senario etc ....

Comment: show us the actual code you are using